# Erase contents of only one layer in Flash CS6

Tags: adobe-flash

I am trying Adobe Flash CS6 for traditional frame-by-frame animation. I am using mainly the pencil tool. When I create a new frame, I often just copy the last keyframe (for every layer) and then perform some modifications. To do so, I need the eraser tool.

I couldn't help but notice that the eraser tool erases stuff from ALL layers. I have read online that this is how it has always been - you need to lock all other layers.

This sounds quite ridiculous. Is this indeed the case? Is there no way to erase my pencil strokes in one particular layer, without having to lock and unlock all others?

If there really is no other way, is there at least a shortcut to quickly lock/unlock all layers except for the currently selected one?

Answer (score 0):

If you **alt-click** on the a layer's lock button, it should lock every layer apart from that one. As far as I can see, there doesn't seem to be any other way of getting around it. It is fairly odd behaviour.

Answer (score -2):

alt+click on the (the one you want to not lock) layer, it should lock every other layer except that one. There is probably no other way except manually doing it.